# Is there any way to load FaceNet model as a tf.keras.layers.Layer using Tensorflow 2.3?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, layer, facenet

I want to use FaceNet as a embedding layer (which won't be trainable).

I tried loading FaceNet like so :

```py
tf.keras.models.load_model('./path/tf_facenet')
```

where directory `./path/tf_facenet` contains 4 files that can be downloaded at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MzpY9kBtDVZ2RpVDYwWmxoSUk/edit
but a message error shows up :

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./path/tf_facenet/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

And the h5 files downloaded from https://github.com/nyoki-mtl/keras-facenet doesn't seem to work either (they use tensorflow 1.3)

Answer (score 0):

I had issued like you when load model facenet-keras. Maybe you python env missing h5py modules.
So you should install that `conda install h5py`
Hope you success!!!

Comment: p/s: my env: 
 + python:3.7
 + tensorflow: 2.4.1